# excel, getting the average of the rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I have a `2000X10` matrix, I want to get a the average of the columns of each row and on the 11th column put all the averages, thus have a `1X2000` matrix with the averages

How can I do that most efficiently? without just doing this

`=AVERAGE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1,J1)`

Comment: What is wrong with the current approach? You have to enter the formula just once and then click the autofill to fill the 2000 Rows

Answer (score 0):

This is shorter and easier to read:

```
=AVERAGE(A1:J1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps:

1. In column k row 1 you can use `=AVERAGE(A1:J1)` to take the average of columns 1 through 10
2. Then copy that value by clicking that cell and pushing ctrl+c  on the keyboard.
3. Next, left click on cell K2 just below where you took your average.
4. Scroll down to the button of your sheet and
5. Hold down SHIFT and left CLICK the last row (row 2000) in column k.
6. Paste with ctrl+V to fill in.  Excel will automatically update the equation to take the average of the rows.

[image: The Result]

Answer (score 0):

For minimal keying: select your eleven columns, Insert > Tables - Table, OK, select the top blank cell of your 11th column, Home > Editing - AutoSum, append "/10" in the cell contents window and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.